# Setting External Id via SObject.put()

Tags: apex, externalid

When I try to set the lookup field with the external id, everything works fine:

```
Account a = new Account();
a.AccountExternal_ID__c = 'abc';

Car__c c = new Car__c();
c.Account__r = a;
insert c;
```

But, when I want to do it with the base SObject type, I get an exception `Invalid field Account__r for Car__c:

```
Account a = new Account();
a.AccountExternal_ID__c = 'abc';

Car__c c = new Car__c();
Sobject so = c;

so.put('Account__r', a);
insert so;
```

Is there any way to make it work, without querying the accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [SObject.putSobject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_putSObject) instead of just [SObject.put](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put). The former is used to set reference fields, and is even explicitly mentioned as the preferred method of setting SObject values for External Id values:

> Sets the value for the specified field. **This method is primarily used with dynamic DML for setting external IDs**. The method returns the previous value of the field. (Emphasis mine).